# Add Table To Database In MVC and Web Api Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have made a project in which i have choose **MVC + Web Api** template with Authorized attribute.I have made my **SQL Data base on Windows Azure** and publish my project successfully.I can see the data of the registered user in users table.
Now i wanted to add one more table to my Database but i am not getting how to do it.I know i have to make a model of that table type and update the database.But i don't getting how to write this part in code.I am total newbie in this part.
I have seen Account controller class it is looking just an alien to me :)

can somebody help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Create the model for your table

```
public class Comment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
}
```

Step2: Add a dbSet for this model in your DbContext class

```
public class DDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DDBContext()
    {
      /* ... */
    }
    // add the DbSet
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    //... additional models ommitted

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DDBContext, Configuration>());
    }
}
```

Step 3: Enable Migrations

In the packagemanager console issue those commands:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration MyNewTableAdded
```

Step 4: Build the project

Step 5: Issue the `update-database` command in the packagemanager console

There is a detailed explanation on www.asp.net including the process for Azure. [Click here!](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)